# scrlttr2: yourref and place don't mix?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

when I specify a place, but not a letter reference in the `*.tex` file, it shows as expected next to the date on the output, but not if a letter reference is specified.

Why is that, and can it be remedied?

```
\documentclass[
  foldmarks=false,
  version=last,
  backaddress=false, %%window envel
  fromalign=left,
  fromrule=false,
  %subject=titled,%% Concernant:
  NF
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\begin{document}


\setkomavar{fromname}{Jacques Dupont}
\setkomavar{place}{Paris} %% wiped out by yourref
\setkomavar{subject}{Philat\'elie}
\setkomavar{yourref}{123}
%\setkomavar{location}{Paris}

\begin{letter}{Jean Durand}
  \opening{Monsieur,}
  Faisant suite \`a notre rencontre...
  \closing{Veuillez agr\'eer, Monsieur, mes salutations distingu\'ees,}

\ps PS: ...
\encl{Les timbres que je vous ai promis}
\cc{Michel Dupond}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chapter 22:

```
\KOMAoptions{
  refline=nodate,
  ...}
}
...
\newkomavar*[Fait \`a:]{lieudate}    
\setkomavar{myref}{467}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{lieudate}{Paris, le \usekomavar{date}}
```

[image]

Comment: `myref` and `leiudate`? Where are they coming from? Only one is explained, without saying why. It is also not explained how it is placed. Right now, this answer only helps yourself, but nobody else. The question itself is a bit unclear. I guess that is the reason the downvoter decided to downvote.

Comment: I meant to encourage you to improve your question and answer so that it will help others in the future as well.

Answer (score 4):

Well, on page 423, in chapter 22.1.5 Business line in the KOMA-Script documentation you will find:

> If you want to have your letter without a business line, then instead
>   of it the label and contents of the variable date will be set.

If I write a business letter, I do not add a place to the date (and this behaviour is the default in `scrlttr2` too).

But if you insist in doing this you can use the follwing MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  foldmarks=false,
  version=last,
  backaddress=false, %%window envel
  fromalign=left,
  fromrule=false,
  %subject=titled,%% Concernant:
  NF
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}


\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Jacques Dupont}
\setkomavar{place}{Paris} %% wiped out by yourref
\setkomavar{subject}{Philat\'elie}

% Geschäftszeile
\setkomavar{date}{\usekomavar{place}, \today}
\setkomavar{invoice}{2016-111}
\setkomavar{yourref}{123}
\setkomavar{myref}{myref}
\setkomavar{yourmail}{yourmail}
%\setkomavar{location}{Paris}

\begin{letter}{Jean Durand}
  \opening{Monsieur,}
  Faisant suite \`a notre rencontre...
  \closing{Veuillez agr\'eer, Monsieur, mes salutations distingu\'ees,}

\ps PS: ...
\encl{Les timbres que je vous ai promis}
\cc{Michel Dupond}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Please see that I used the line `\setkomavar{date}{\usekomavar{place}, \today}` to change the `date` entry for the business line to that what you perhaps want.

This is the result:

[image: pdf with changed business line]

Just comment the lines after `% Geschäftszeile` to get the non business letter.

Comment: @Erwann Well, I do not know the "rules" for frensh letters and business letters. I as a German would not add the place in a german business letter.  So I showed you how you can do it, if you really want this solution ...  Please consider to upvote (with more rep) and accept my answer, if it solved your problem ...